# Android - change font size of spinner from code

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm updating the font size of all the texts on the app, what I want to achieve is, when I select the font size, i should be able to update the font sizes of all the texts on that activity.

My only problem is i can't find the `size` property on the Spinner Object.
This is what I did for Text Views, is it possible to apply a code similar to this one for Spinners ?

```
const val HEADER_TEXT = 24
const val NORMAL_TEXT = 14

private fun updateAssetSize(textView: TextView, additionalSize: Int, type: Int) {
     val size = additionalSize + type
     textView.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size.toFloat());
}

//calling the method:
updateAssetSize(screenText, additionalFontSize, HEADER_TEXT)
```

**Note: This should be done from code, since this will be updated on run time.**

[image]

Comment: you can do that by using custom adapter for the spinner and change the text size within `getView()` method.

Comment: I'll try this, thank you!

Comment: No, this one is changing the size via xml. I'll try the suggestion of @Zain and provide an answer once I'm done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Zain Suggestion, I resolved this by using an adapterlist object. Instead of using `String` I created a custom class with fontSize and text properties in it.

```
class SpinnerItem(
    val text: String,
    var fontSize: Int
) {


    // this is necessary, in order for the text to display the texts in the dropdown list
    override fun toString(): String {
        return text
    }
}
```

Here's the AdapterList that I created:

```
class SpinnerItemListAdapter(
    context: Context,
    val resourceId: Int,
    var list: ArrayList<SpinnerItem>
) : ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>(context, resourceId, list) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val text = this.list[position].text
        val size = this.list[position].fontSize
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false)

        val simpleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleTextView) as TextView
        simpleTextView.text = text
        simpleTextView.setTextSize(size.toFloat())

        return convertView
    }

    // We'll call this whenever there's an update in the fontSize
    fun swapList(list: ArrayList<SpinnerItem>) {
        clear()
        addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Here's the custom XML File **spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simpleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

The Spinner to be updated:

```
var fontSizes = arrayListOf(
    SpinnerItem("Small", NORMAL_TEXT, "Default"),
    SpinnerItem("Normal", NORMAL_TEXT, "Default"),
    SpinnerItem("Large", NORMAL_TEXT, "Default"),
    SpinnerItem("Largest", NORMAL_TEXT, "Default")
)

var fontSizeAdapterItem = SpinnerItemListAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.spinner_item,
                toSpinnerItemList(fontSizes, newSize)
            )
```

Here's What will happen when we update it:

```
private fun updateSpinnerSize(additional: Int) {
        val newSize = additional + NORMAL_TEXT

        fontSizes = toSpinnerItemList(fontSizes, newSize)

        fontSizeAdapterItem?.let {
            it.swapList(fontSizes)
        }
    }

private fun toSpinnerItemList(
        list: ArrayList<SpinnerItem>,
        newSize: Int
    ): ArrayList<SpinnerItem> {
        val itemList = ArrayList<SpinnerItem>()

        for (item in list) {
            item.fontSize = newSize
            itemList.add(item)
        }
        return itemList
    }
```